# Python script to extract json field

Tags: json, python-3.x

I wrote this little script to extract a specific JSON field passed in from command line.  It works and all but it seems inefficient.   Any suggestion on any improvement?

jsonx.py name jdoe.json will return "John Doe"
jsonx.py rec.course jdoe.json  will return "Java"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
import json

def main():
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0

    argc = len(sys.argv)

    if argc == 2:
        field = sys.argv[1]
        infile = sys.stdin

    elif argc == 3:
        field = sys.argv[1]
        infile = open(sys.argv[2], 'rb')

    else:
        raise SystemExit(sys.argv[0] + " <json-field> [ <json-file> ]")

    with infile:
        try:
            obj = json.load(infile)

        except(ValueError, e):
            raise SystemExit(e)

    for f in [f for f in re.split("[\.\[\]]", field) if f != '']:
        try:
            if f.isdigit():
                obj = obj[int(f)]

            else:
                obj = obj[f]

        except(ValueError, e):
            raise SystemExit(e)

    print(obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample json file:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "rec": {
        "id": 1,
        "course": "Java"
    }
}
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear! How `jsonx.py name jdoe.json will return "John Doe"` ?

Comment: Why is it inefficient?

Comment: @Ghanem because it will extract `name` attribute from `jdoe.json`

Comment: @Binh ,  split the field and loop through.  Is there something like  obj."${field}".  where field could be rec.course...   ..

Comment: @Ghanem,  There was typo in the sample json.  I just corrected .   yes.   jsonx.py name will return "John Doe" ,  see the updated sample json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` and `operator` like this:

```
x = {"name": "John Doe", "rec": {"id": 1, "course": "Java"}}

from functools import reduce
import operator

def get_dict(mydict, list_attr):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, list_attr, mydict)
```

Try it out:

```
>>> get_dict(x, ['rec', 'course'])
Java
>>> get_dict(x, ['name'])
John Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the array handling:

```
def get_dict(x, field):
    fields = [f for f in re.split("[\.\[\]]", field) if f != '']
    fields = [(int(i) if i.isdigit() else i) for i in fields]
    return reduce(operator.getitem, fields, x)
```